# Number of functions satisfying $\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^1(f(x))^2dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The number of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to R$ that satisfy $$\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^1(f(x))^2dx$$
is

(A) $0$

(B) $1$

(C) $2$

(D) infinity

My Attempt:

$$\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^1(f(x))^2dx$$

$$\int_{0}^1\left(\frac{f(x)}{2}-x\right)^2dx=0$$

which gives $$f(x)=2x$$

So it appears there is only one function.

But then is this $f(x)$ unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $f(x)=2x$ is the only continuous solution based on the following implication:

> The only non-negative function $g(x):[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfying $\int_0^1 g(x)dx=0$ is $g(x)=0$.

To show this, note that if $g(x_0)=l>0$ for some $x_0\in[0,1]$, then
$$
\exists \delta>0\quad,\quad 0<|x-x_0|<\delta \ \ ,\ \ 0<x<1\implies |g(x)-l|<\frac{l}{2} 
$$
which means that $g(x)$ is above $\frac{l}{2}$ in a non-zero interval, yielding a positive value for $\int_0^1 g(x)dx$. This contradiction finally proves **the uniqueness of your solution.**

Comment: Ok. Let us go step by step. Do you confirm that $\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^1(f(x))^2dx$ is equivalent to $\int_{0}^1\left(\frac{f(x)}{2}-x\right)^2dx=0$? In not, please tell me which part of the equivalence is wrong.

Comment: Put $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ in the given equation and you will see that are infinitely many triples $(A,B,C)$ which satisfy the equation. If you put B=0 and C=2 then you get a fixed A. Clearly, $f(x)=2x$ is not the only function

Comment: Excuse me to ask this. Do you say this by intuition or you have tested for and found some values for $(A,B,C)$?

Comment: I did . By doing some calculation I arrived at $f(x)=\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{35}}{2}\right)x^2+2$

Comment: Our whole argument in support of $f(x)=2x$ rests upon the fact that we are expressing 1/3 in a particular way

Comment: You may put A=1, B=1 and solve for C to get another f(x).

Comment: You are right. I made a grave calculation error. Please ignore my comments

Comment: It's ok. I'm happy I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it’s unique since $(f(x)/2 - x)^2$ is always $\ge 0$ so for the integral to be equal to $0$ you can just solve $(f(x)/2 -x)^2=0$

Comment: But $\frac{1}{3}=\int_{0}^1\frac{2x}{3}dx$. Also if we take $f(x)$ as a polynomial of degree n over R then we shall get an equation in (n+2) unknowns which can be taken in infinitely many ways

Comment: @Maverick Since the inner function is greater than equal to $0$ the integral from $0$ to $1$ will also be greater than $0$ (think in terms of area) . Solve the equation by taking the square root  adding $x$ then multiplying by $2$.

Comment: What you say is true but there are many ways in which a number can be expressed in terms of definite integral

Comment: @Maverick Let $g$ be another function satisfying the equation you proved that it must satisfy the integral equation equal to $0$ and this answer proves that it hence must be $2x$

Comment: @Maverick Can you give an example of another solution ?

Comment: $f(x)=\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{35}}{2}\right)x^2+2$

Comment: Why does it SA’s tidy the equation @Maverick

Comment: $f(x)=\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{35}}{2}\right)x^2+2$
See,I assumed $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ and put
it in given equation. I got an equation in terms of A,B and C. I have one equation in 3 variables which is bound to have infinite number of solutions

Comment: It does not satisfy $(f(x)/2 -x)^2=0$ @Maverick

Comment: True. But it will satisfy the original equation which should be our concern

Comment: You may put A=1, B=1 and solve for C to get another f(x).

Comment: You are right. I made a grave calculation mistake. So please ignore my comments

Comment: As a general point, if you have even only one polynomial equation in 3 variables over the real numbers $\mathbb R$ it need not have any solutions, e.g. $x^2+y^2+z^2 +1=0$. Over $\mathbb C$, any polynomial equation will always have solutions, but over $\mathbb R$ you cannot assume this.